# RealmResults filter query with Exact String

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a realm database where a field `postCategories` contains random string type data fetched from server through JSON. Those String values looks similar to the followings:

```
Semester - I, Marketing, English Version, Short Question
B.Com., Semester - II, E-Commerce, English Version, Broad Question
Semester - III, Marketing, English Version, Short Question
Semester - IV, Company Law, Bengali Version, Short Question
.......
```

Now, I want to filter RealmResults only where `postCategories` contains `Semester - I`or `Semester - II` or `Semester - III` or `Semester - IV`any one, separately. what should I do?

I tried following codes to find all data where `postCategories` contains `Semester - I` :

```
RealmResults<RealmTitle> realmTitles;
realmTitles = realm.where(RealmTitle.class)
            .contains("postCategories", "Semester - I").findAll();
```

but this gives all data of `Semester - I`, `Semester - II`, `Semester - III` and `Semester - IV`.

I can find a temporary Solution as follows.

```
realmTitles = realm.where(RealmTitle.class)
                .contains("postCategories", "Semester - I")
                .and().not()
                .contains("postCategories", "Semester - II").findAll();
```

This is to prevent `Semester - II` to be added with the Result. But this doesn't seems like a good solution. Please help me to find more appropriate solution of this.

Thank you. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Select Semester I or II or III or IV try filtering by pattern i.e. not to have 2 "Semester - I" in one postCategories:

```
realmTitles = realm
   .where(RealmTitle.class)
   .contains("postCategories", "Semester - I")
   .and().not().like("postCategories", "*Semester - I*Semester - *")
   .findAll();
```

If it is important to exclude Semester IV

```
realmTitles = realm
   .where(RealmTitle.class)
   .contains("postCategories", "Semester - I")
   .and().not().like("postCategories", "*Semester - I*Semester - *")
   .and().not().contains("postCategories", "Semester - IV")
   .findAll();
```

If you want to have only those which have i.e. only Semester I:

```
realmTitles = realm
   .where(RealmTitle.class)
   .like("postCategories", "*Semester - I")
   .or().contains("postCategories", "Semester - I,")
   .and().not().like("postCategories", "*Semester - *Semester - *")
   .findAll();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Adding a comma is good solution. ex: .contains("postCategories", "Semester - I,") But this string is saved from JSON which is created from server. That is why I don't have a control over it. some of the categories may be at the end of the list, like "B.Com., Marketing, English Version, Semester - I". Is there any solution to filter exact string Excluding any character attached to that string?

Comment: updated the query to handle the case with Semester at the end of list

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @GiorgosDev What if want to create query for dynamic comma separated strings and dynamically filter those string?